# Spark 2.1.1 DataFrame gives incorrect column when select() method is used

Tags: apache-spark

I am using the below schema to create a DataFrame using Spark's Data Source API.

```
StructType(Seq(StructField("name", StringType, true), 
                        StructField("age", IntegerType, true),
                        StructField("livesIn", StringType, true),
                        StructField("bornIn", StringType, true)))
```

I am hardcoding the data as shown below in PrunedFilteredScan's buildScan() method:

```
val schemaFields = schema.fields
// hardcoded for now. Need to read from Accumulo and plug it here
val rec = List("KBN 1000000 Universe Parangipettai", "Sreedhar 38 Mysore Adoni", "Siva 8 Hyderabad Hyderabad",
                "Rishi 23 Blr Hyd", "Ram 45 Chn Hyd", "Abey 12 Del Hyd")

// Reading from Accumulo done. Constructing the RDD now for DF.
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(rec)        
rdd.count
val rows = rdd.map(rec => {
  //println("file ===============>"+file)
  val fields = rec.split(" ")

  val typeCastedValues = fields.zipWithIndex.map{
    case (value, index) => {
      //println(s"PRUNED val: ${value} - index: ${index}")

      val dataType = schemaFields(index).dataType
      typeCast(value, dataType)
    }
  }
  Row.fromSeq(typeCastedValues)
})
rows }
private def typeCast(value: String, toType: DataType) = toType match {
case _: StringType      => value
case _: IntegerType     => value.toInt }
```

When I create DataFrame as shown below:

```
val dfPruned = sqlContext.read.format(dsPackage).load().select("livesIn")
dfPruned.show
dfPruned.printSchema
```

It gives me `name` column's data for header `livesIn`. Please help if I am missing anything or this is a bug in Spark 2.1.1
[Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoh2K.png)

```
+--------+
| livesIn|
+--------+
|     KBN|
|Sreedhar|
|    Siva|
|   Rishi|
|     Ram|
|    Abey|
+--------+

root
 |-- livesIn: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to apply a schema for your rdd you can use `createDataFrame` function as below.

```
   // create a row from your data by splitting wit " "
   val rows = rdd.map( value => {
      val data = value.split(" ")
   // you could use Rows.fromSeq(data) but since you need second field as int needs conversion

      Row(data(0), data(1).toInt, data(2), data(3))
    })

   //creating a dataframe with rows and schema 
    val df = sparkContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)


    // selecting only column livesIn 
    df.select("livesIn")
```

Output:

```
+---------+
|  livesIn|
+---------+
| Universe|
|   Mysore|
|Hyderabad|
|      Blr|
|      Chn|
|      Del|
+---------+
```

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks Shankar. However, I need to implement this extending Spark's Data Source API, but not using createDataFrame() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your `dataframe` when you have `schema` and when you have converted your `rdd` as `Rows` as

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
```

Then when you do

```
val dfPruned = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema).select("livesIn")
dfPruned.show
dfPruned.printSchema
```

you should be getting output as

```
+---------+
|  livesIn|
+---------+
| Universe|
|   Mysore|
|Hyderabad|
|      Blr|
|      Chn|
|      Del|
+---------+

root
 |-- livesIn: string (nullable = true)
```

**Edited**

If you want to use the Data Source API, then its more simple

```
sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", " ").schema(schema).load("path to your file ").select("livesIn")
```

should do the trick.

**NOTE**: I am using input file as following

```
KBN 1000000 Universe Parangipettai
Sreedhar 38 Mysore Adoni
Siva 8 Hyderabad Hyderabad
Rishi 23 Blr Hyd
Ram 45 Chn Hyd
Abey 12 Del Hyd
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. However, I need to implement this extending Spark's Data Source API, but not using createDataFrame() method.